# What is the proper way to invoke Keycloak's end_session_endpoint

Tags: keycloak

Environment: Keycloak 12.0.4

We plan to allow various OpenIDC-protected applications to initiate a "single sign-out" using Keycloak's end_session_endpoint. In our case, we'd like to provide our own URL that applications will hit when they want to sign-out.  That URL will either programmatically invoke the end_session_endpoint or simply redirect the user's browser to that endpoint.

The Keycloak documentation and examples I've seen so far are a bit confusing regarding how to invoke this endpoint.  For example, do I need to add a query parameter with the id token as a value?  (I noticed, for example, that mod_auth_openidc includes an id_token_hint query param.) I assume this call has to be authenticated, so do I include the client id/secret as the credentials?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some additional information from the keycloak-user group which I think completely answers the question:

> You can look at
> https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0-17.html#RPLogout.
> From our implementation, we rely on either cookies or the
> id_token_hint to identify the user and logout sessions. So you don't
> necessarily need to send id_token_hint if cookies are sent when
> redirecting the user from your application to Keycloak. You can also
> send a state param to match if the logout action sent to your
> application originated from a valid logout request.
>
> Note, however, that we don't force the id_token_hint and do not ask
> the user for confirmation, as per spec. But there are discussions to
> introduce a consent page.
>
> In regards to logout, messages are sent to clients through the
> backchannel.

Edit: Here's the actual (latest) RP-initated logout spec: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html.

Answer (score 4):

You have standard how to call RP-Initiated Logout:
https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html#RPLogout

> An RP requests that the OP log out the End-User by redirecting the End-User's User Agent to the OP's Logout Endpoint.

It is a redirect, not API call, because you very likely wants to delete also IDP session (cookies on used Keycloak domain in your case).

Comment: Thank you.  I don't know why I didn't just look at the spec!

Answer (score 3):

The logout URL needs to be build from

- the OpenID Connect end session endpoint
- a target redirect URI where the user should be sent after logout, provided as query param `post_logout_redirect_uri`
- The encoded ID token as query param `id_token_hint`

In Spring it can be built like this:

```
String logoutLink = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(endSessionEndpoint)
  .queryParam("post_logout_redirect_uri", logoutUrlEncoded)
  .queryParam("id_token_hint", 
    ((OidcUser) authentication.getPrincipal()).getIdToken().getTokenValue())
  .build().toUriString();
```